# Image_tag and turbolink

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I started my journey with Rails and Ruby a couple of days ago and so far it is going well and I'm loving it!

Though, I do have a minor concern that I cannot find a solution to. I've had a minor sneak peek on turbolink and how that is embedded with Rails.  But, my question (problem?) is that whenever I import/include an image (which is located in *app/assets/image*) with Rails `image_tag(...)`, that image is reloaded whenever I redirect to another page. *But* if I use `<img src="..."` whereas the src is an extern link (image fetched from another page) it is not being re-fetched (meaning, it's cached when I redirect to another page).

So my question is: is there a special way to apply turbolink to `image_tag`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are running in development mode. Rails uses an "Asset Pipeline. When in development environment it reloads the assets.

When you come to production, you will see the difference.

You can read more about it here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply!

Comment: If it helps please mark as answer :) I'd appreciate it

Comment: I was unaware of that. Thanks for enlightening me on my problem.

Comment: You will find with rails it does ALOT under the hood, this can be great but also very frustrating when you don't know why things are doing what they are. Good luck mate